# my server / client project not working

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a server project with socket and a client project with socket in c#, that, when I start my server project, my form is not working, like is lock.
please help me...

What do I do for resolving that my form works and textbox shows messages?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            port = 11000;
            ip = IPAddress.Any;
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
            socketServer = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socketServer.Bind(ipLocal);
            socketServer.Listen(10);
            buffersize = 1024;//از این سایزه همه چی از گووره این در می آد
            newClient = socketServer.Accept();
            while (true)
            {
                buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                recv = newClient.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                if (recv != 0)
                {
                    message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
                    textBox1.Text += message;
                    //socketServer.Close();
                    //newClient.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

in client:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bufferSize = 1024;
            ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10");
            port = 11000;
            socketClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
            socketClient.Connect(ipEnd);
            while (true)
            {
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                message = textBox1.Text;
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                snd = socketClient.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                //socketClient.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Server :

You problem is due to blocking nature of Socket.Recieve() [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

It says :

> If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available

And you run this in same UI thread, so you feel your UI to be freeze.

Solution : Transfer your socket function to another thread. And to update text box, use [Invokes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also in your implementation both Server and Client, you run a while loop infinitely. Since they are running in UI thread, you will feel the freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Your applications locks up because you have an infinite loop in you click event handlers. You will have to start a Thread to do the read and write operations as not to block your main visualization thread.